# Adding an entry to a SharePoint Choice field is erroring out in IE

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2013

I have the following code that adds an entry to a choice field and it works fine in Chrome.  However, it is not working in IE.  I thought it did work in IE with an earlier version, but not be certain.  The code that works in Chrome (Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and does not work in IE (Version 11.55.177.63.0) is:

```
$('select[title="Status"]').append(`<option value="Approved">Approved</option>`);
```

The error message from IE is:  **Invalid character**.  When looking at the actual error in the console window, the above line has 'select[title="Status"]' in red and then the Parentheses for the append function are shaded with a small rectangular box.

How do I find a statement that will add the Approved choice option in my choice field Status?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Template literals (Template strings) in your code.ES6 do not support IE.
[image]
Just change the code to :

```
$('select[title="Status"]').append('<option value="Approved">Approved</option>');
```

Comment: I used single quotes,  you used the template string.